# Power Apps: View "Edit History" Of A Forms Responses

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I developed an App where users can fill out a form. Upon hitting :Submit: > the responses are Patched to a DataVerse list > The DataVerse List of Patched responses are then displayed in a Gallery. In this Gallery users can EDIT the responses or view the summary. I need to have an additional option to VIEW CHANGES made, if the user edits a Tile.

Currently, the user can make edits and REPATCH a NEW submission. So if a record is edited 3 times, there are 3 new Gallery tiles, which isnt what I want. I was given suggestions to use the Primary unique ID for the original submission, and some secondary ID for edits and then attach the secondary ID to the main one so all "edit/resubmissions" can be displayed when the primary is called, but I have no idea how to do that... PLEASE if you have any suggestions or have created an "edit history" for form responses that WASNT based off the employee ID/User ID rather it was based off submission ticket/request, I really need the help.

Comment: can you show us the value of the OnSelect property when you are trying to repatching a submission ?

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA I only have one patch button on the main form, that is the button that patches to DataVerse. It is: https://imgur.com/a/USML0Vt and to repopulate the form from the submission gallery (datasource: DataVerse patches) they can click the edit button the variable in the second image. How can I make a patch button be visible dependent on if it's accessed through the edit button?